# Git Bash under Windows reporting errors, but git under FreeBSD not

Tags: git, github, ide

My project is located on remote server, running FreeBSD.
My home PC is running Windows and I have local drive mounted via SSH to this remote FreeBSD server.

As version control system I'm using `git` provided by GitHub.

When I'm running `git status` from FreeBSD under project folder - everything is okay.
But when I'm running `git status` from the **same project folder** under Windows my Git Bash is saying `fatal: loose object b33edafa4d6108187f6b1c232fc68685b982ba63 (stored in .git/objects/b3/3edafa4d6108187f6b1c232fc68685b982ba63) is corrupt`

I've tried running `git fsck` on directly on FreeBSD machine - everything is ok with repository: `Checking object directories: 100% (256/256), done.`

But I've tried running the same command `git fsck` using Windows's Git Bash on same project folder - I'm getting this error: `Checking object directories: 100% (256/256), done.
fatal: loose object 01a6dcd554545da0b1fa191e11f3406a5ded7581 (stored in .git/obj
ects/01/a6dcd554545da0b1fa191e11f3406a5ded7581) is corrupt`

Why git on FreeBSD is not reporting any errors, but Windows Git Bash is reporting? I'm doing all commands on the same project folder.

Comment: So you have an sshfs mount from Windows? Have you tried copying the files over to Windows to check if it works locally? If *that* works, it would mean it's something that the sshfs layer is doing.